# Using StickerKit from Snapchat in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, snapchat, snapkit

I am trying to add a sticker with contents of a url photo to post to snapchat.

snapAPI.startSending(snapContent) shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS

and I get a warning:

warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

```
     } else if category == "Share to Snapchat" {

        let url = URL(string: "")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        let stickerImage = image!
        let sticker = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerImage: stickerImage)
        let snapContent = SCSDKNoSnapContent()
        snapContent.sticker = sticker
        snapAPI.startSending(snapContent)
        
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How have you declared snapAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Import this line in podfile

```
pod 'SnapSDK', :subspecs => ['SCSDKLoginKit', 'SCSDKCreativeKit', 'SCSDKBitmojiKit']
```

and then import this-

```
import SCSDKCreativeKit
import SCSDKBitmojiKit
import SCSDKLoginKit
```

Try like this, it works for me.

```
let snapAPI = SCSDKSnapAPI()
let myURL = URL(string: "")
if let myData = try? Data(contentsOf: myURL!) {
    if let myImage = UIImage(data: myData) {
        let sticker = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerImage: myImage)
        let snapContent = SCSDKNoSnapContent()
        snapContent.sticker = sticker
        snapAPI.startSending(snapContent) { (error: Error?) in
             if error == nil {
                     // Success
             }else{
                    // Check the error
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it still shows an error.

Comment: @WhySoSerious33, I have updated my answer. I am doing this way and it works fine.

Comment: Still not working.. What are the other things to check ?

Comment: What is the error now? Getting the warning?

Comment: snapAPI.startSending...

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x16f3a3fb0)

Comment: Check your all variables and classes some variables might be the wrong Inheritance. Updated answer, plz check.